# Hough Circle Transform on Video

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, hough-transform

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):

# Take each frame
_, frame = cap.read() # frame olarak goruntuyu aldık

# BGR ' yi HSV ye çevirdik
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# HSV nin içindeki renk aralıgını belirledik
lower_yellow = np.array([20,0,0])
upper_yellow = np.array([40,255,255])

# Yukarıda belırledıgımız eşik değerlerini gray goruntunun içinde eşleştirdik.
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

# bitwise and operatörü ile de ana goruntude yukarıda buldugumuz mask'i aldık.
res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
img = cv2.medianBlur(res, 5)

cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 5, 20,
                           param1=50, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=10)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0, :]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv2.circle(cimg, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.imshow('detected circles', cimg)
#ayarladıgımız 3 görüntüyü gösterdik

cv2.imshow('res',res)
k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
if k == 27:
    break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run , There is a error called :

```
cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:1494: error: (-215) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function HoughCircles
```

I want to find circle on video .

Comment: `img` within `cv2.HoughCircles()` must be a single channel image. In your case it is a three channel HSV image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`HoughTransform` is only supported on greyscale images](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html#houghcircles)

> `cv2.HoughCircles(image, method, dp, minDist[, circles[, param1[, param2[, minRadius[, maxRadius]]]]]) → circles`
>
> Parameters:  **image – 8-bit, single-channel, grayscale input image.**

Either pick one channel or convert your image to single channel.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah! Hough Circle Transform is for Grayscale images only. So you have to give "**cimg**" (from your code) as input to **HoughCircles**.

Also, you don't have to write this line:

```
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

Comment: Hi Devansh Soni. Please consider adding more information.